# fix a leak for Quick set pool floor pinholes

Tags: leak, pool

I have a quickset style pool that has lots of tiny holes all over the bottom. I think it was because I used the wrong type of chlorine pellets and little flakes fell to the bottom of the pool. I found the product called fix a leak, would it work for this? Thanks!

Comment: what would work for this? ... it is unclear what you are talking about ... if you are talking about some specific product, then read the user instructions

Comment: I have never used this product but be prepared for plugged filters, I have seen vinyl bleached by tablets but never holes, leaks in this case are primarily from sharp stones in my experience (I put a tarp down even over a bed of fine beach sand to protect the liner). If not really expensive it sounds like it might work at least from their testimonials.

Comment: Directions say to take the filter out, and then after its done to clean the filter regularly for awhile.  Youre probably right, it could have been from the concrete it was on. I had a tarp under it but it was pretty thin. I just thought it happened too suddenly for it to be that but maybe not. Its not very expensive ($12 a small bottle) but im not sure its made for vinyl pools. It says it works for almost any material but I am only seeing it used on concrete pools so far. Also would it glue the pool to my patio? LOL

Comment: If it leaks unaceptably, i fear it will need replaced. You might try a bottle of tire sealant (white goop, not fix-a-flat). Pour some on, then squeegee off; the holes should retain product and cure to a tight seal.

Answer (score 0):

The vinyl cement I've used for patching my pool indicates that it can be applied wet (under water) and I've done that several times to patch the pool while it is filled. Does this not work for your situation?

Comment: It doesnt need to be applied wet, thats not the problem. The problem is there is hundreds of tiny holes so I really dont wanna patch them by hand, I think it would take too long. I almost need some kind of coating I can coat the entire bottom with.